# ionic hide navbar on ng-click

Tags: angularjs, navbar, fade, ionic-framework

I would like to hide my navbar on ng-click, but somehow the transition is not working.

Could you help me understand the problem?

```
.nav-bar{
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: 0.25s;
  transition: 0.25s;
  -webkit-transition-property: all !important;
  transition-property: all !important;
}
.bar-header-fade-away{
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all linear 0.25s;
  transition: all linear 0.25s;
  transition-property: all !important;
  -webkit-transition-property: all !important;
}
```

My controller

```
$scope.toggleUI = function(){
    $scope.showui = !$scope.showui;
    $rootScope.fadeHeader = !$rootScope.fadeHeader;
}
```

My View

```
<ion-nav-bar align-title="center" class="nav-bar bar-purple" ng-show="fadeHeader">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're overcomplicating things. To hide the nav bar on click, your view should be something like:

```
<ion-nav-bar align-title="center" class="nav-bar bar-purple" ng-show="fadeHeader" ng-click="showHideHeader()">
    <ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>
```

And then in the controller:

```
$scope.fadeHeader = false;

$scope.showHideHeader = function() {
    $scope.fadeHeader = !$scope.fadeHeader;
};
```

Bear in mind than when you click it and it hides, there's no getting it back without reloading the page.